# Xcode unable to find Eigen in workspace

Tags: xcode, cgal, eigen3

I'm working on Xcode 7.0.1. I'm working with CGAL 4.7. I have a mesh that I want to refine using fair() and refine() as shown in [this](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2refine_fair_example_8cpp-example.html#a4) example.

I initially copied the code and ran it in Xcode and it gave me this error:

**/Users/.../Desktop/CGAL-4.7/include/CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/fair.h:133:5: Static_assert failed "The function `fair` requires Eigen3 version 3.2 or later."**

Subsequently, I added `usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.6/lib` and `usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.6/include/eigen` to Library Search Path and Header Search Path. Eigen is working, I run some sample code to test. But, I'm still getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#title56) you can set the environment variable `EIGEN3_INC_DIR` to the directory contain the `Eigen` directory containing the header files before running CMake.

Comment: Hi, i did what you suggested, and then ran cake and make, (with the with-eigen flag checked as well in the cake gui), and the cake output seemed fine, theres even my path to eigen in cmakecache.txt, but Xcode gives me the same error after relinking the binaries etc. how do i make sure, that cgal was, in fact built with eigen3 this time?

Comment: You don't need to build CGAL with Eigen. The `With_Eigen` flags is cmake is not needed. Note that you need to run cmake for the example and see a line containing `-- Found Eigen3`